# While loop inside if else statement not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code snippet that is failing to work, don't know what am doing wrong, am getting content from MYSQL database and using `if else` statement with `while` loop to echo the contents.

```
<?php 

                if ($row_item['cat_item_id'] == ''){
                        echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"">

                        </p>
                        <p>
                          No Item To Show
                        </p>
                      </div>
                  </div>';
                    }

                else  {                       
                  while ($row_item = mysql_fetch_assoc($item)){
                      echo
                  '
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="'.$row_item['display'].'">
                      <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="myaccount/user_data/'.$row_item['file_name'].'" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="caption">
                        <h3>'.$row_item['item_name'].'</h3>
                                             <p>
                          <a href="item_detail.php?item='.$row_item['cat_item_id'].'" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">
                           View Item
                          </a> 
                          <a href="contact_seller.php?contact='.$row_item['cat_item_id'].'" class="btn btn-default" role="button">
                          Contact Owner
                          </a>
                        </p>
                      </div>
                  </div>';
                  }

                }

                    ?>
```

Help me figure out what am not doing right.

Comment: are you sure $item is a resource and not a failed query? Also, switch to mysqli or pdo. mysql_ is deprecated

Comment: add a little love to your code, it pains me to see your formatting/invalid html

Comment: Not an answer but (as @KaiQing mentioned) please use _mysqli_ extention because eventually _mysql_ extension will be deprecated. See here http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call  while ($row_item = mysql_fetch_assoc($item))
first place.

Otherwise the $row_items doesn't get initialized properly.

So you put all inside

```
 while ($row_item = mysql_fetch_assoc($item))
```

And check for the if-else conditions inside the while:

```
if ($row_item['cat_item_id'] == '') // this goes inside the while. Otherwise $row_item is not initialized properly
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if

```
if ($row_item['cat_item_id'] == ''){
```

before you actually call

```
while ($row_item = mysql_fetch_assoc($item)){
```

To get `$row_item`

---

Try changing it to something like this:

```
while ($row_item = mysql_fetch_assoc($item)){
    if ($row_item['cat_item_id'] == ''){

        echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"">
              </p>
              <p>No Item To Show</p></div></div>';

    }else  {

        echo
                  '
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="'.$row_item['display'].'">
                      <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="myaccount/user_data/'.$row_item['file_name'].'" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="caption">
                        <h3>'.$row_item['item_name'].'</h3>
                                             <p>
                          <a href="item_detail.php?item='.$row_item['cat_item_id'].'" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">
                           View Item
                          </a> 
                          <a href="contact_seller.php?contact='.$row_item['cat_item_id'].'" class="btn btn-default" role="button">
                          Contact Owner
                          </a>
                        </p>
                      </div>
                  </div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **mysql_fetch_array**

```
while ($row_item = mysql_fetch_array($item)){
                  echo
              '
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="'.$row_item['display'].'">
                  <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="myaccount/user_data/'.$row_item['file_name'].'" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="caption">
                    <h3>'.$row_item['item_name'].'</h3>
                                         <p>
                      <a href="item_detail.php?item='.$row_item['cat_item_id'].'" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">
                       View Item
                      </a> 
                      <a href="contact_seller.php?contact='.$row_item['cat_item_id'].'" class="btn btn-default" role="button">
                      Contact Owner
                      </a>
                    </p>
                  </div>
              </div>';
              }
```